# Validation is not working for empty fields

Tags: jquery

I have 5 input fields with class `hidden`

```
<section class="hidden">
        <label>
        <input class="required" ng-model="currentData.name" /> 
         </label>     
</section>
<section>
        <label>
        <input  class="required" ng-model="currentData.id"/> 
        </label>   
</section>
<section>
    <label>
    <input class="required" type="text" ng-model='currentData.age'/>  
    </label>  
</section>
<section class="hidden">
    <label>
    <input class="required" ng-model='currentData.gender'/> 
    </label>
</section>
<section>
    <label>
    <input class="required" ng-model='currentData.description'/>
    </label>    
</section>
```

I am doing validation for empty fields,its working good.

```
$form('input.required').each(function() {
            if ($this.val().trim() == '') {
                alert()
            }       
        })
```

Now I dont want to do validation for fields which parent section element has `hidden` class.This is the code I have written.

```
$form.find('section').not(".hidden").closest('input.required').each(function() {
            if ($this.val().trim() == '') {
                alert()
            }       
        })
```

But my problem is validation is not working for fields even it has no `hidden` class.
If I remove `.not()` method validation is working.What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Closest` is to select in parent nodes, you are suppose to use `find` instead of `closest`.

```
$form.find('section').not(".hidden").find('input.required').each(function() {
    if ($this.val().trim() == '') {
       alert()
    }       
    });
```

Check below snippet for reference.

```js
$('.btn').click(function() {
  $('section').not('.hidden').find('input.required').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val().trim() == '') {
      alert()
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="hidden">
  <label>
    <input class="required" ng-model="currentData.name" />
  </label>
</section>
<section>
  <label>
    <input class="required" ng-model="currentData.id" />
  </label>
</section>
<section>
  <label>
    <input class="required" type="text" ng-model='currentData.age' />
  </label>
</section>
<section class="hidden">
  <label>
    <input class="required" ng-model='currentData.gender' />
  </label>
</section>
<section>
  <label>
    <input class="required" ng-model='currentData.description' />
  </label>
</section>

<input type="button" value="click" class="btn">
```